# order by JSON data type postgres

Tags: json, postgresql

I have a Postgres table which has column of type JSON which has a bunch of JSON objects in them. I want to query the table records and order the results by a value stored in the JSON field. I'm getting the queries to run, but they don't sort correctly. I'm not finding a ton of documentation on ordering JSON field types specifically, so hoping someone has run into this.

```
data: {name: "stuff", value: "third option"}
data: {name: "stuff", value: "awesome stuff"}
data: {name: "stuff", value: "way cooler stuff"}
```

The following SQL executes but the results return unordered

```
select * from table ORDER BY data->>'value asc'
```

I'm using rails, but have tried running SQL directly as well w/ same result

Answer (score 83, accepted):

You put `asc` in the fieldname. There's no key named `value asc` in the json, so `data ->> 'value asc'` will always return `NULL`.

You actually want:

```
select * from table ORDER BY data->>'value' ASC
```

to match the json, possibly even:

```
select * 
from table 
WHERE data ->> 'name' = 'stuff'
ORDER BY data->>'value' ASC
```

Comment: I had tried that too. it runs, but still doesn't order the records correctly. (by the values for stuff)  do i need to cast the value or something?

Comment: @user1767105 See update. You're trying to get a non-existent key 'stuff', so it'll be equivalent to `ORDER BY NULL`.

Comment: got it. sorry i had the data objects incorrect above.  really it was data: {"stuff" => {"name" => "stuff", "value": "awesome stuff"}}  query ends up as select....order by data->"stuff"->>"value"  your help got me there though so thanks!   additionally a good resource as well: http://clarkdave.net/2013/06/what-can-you-do-with-postgresql-and-json/

Comment: How is this supposed to work with integer? They seems to be sorted as if they were string: ``1, 10, 46, 6`` rather than ``1, 6, 10, 46``

Comment: @Natim Please post a new, separate question and link to this one for context. Include complete examples.

Comment: I fixed up this question to not have keyboard coding error and adjusted the answers correspondingly

Answer (score 38):

Use `->` instead of `->>` (`->>` gets a JSON object field as text):

```
select * from my_table ORDER BY data->'some_number' asc;
```

Comment: While this does directly answer the question, I am grateful I found this. It helped me to solve a JSON column being sorted alphabetically when it is a number.

Answer (score 19):

Try:

`ORDER BY cast(data->>'value' as integer)  ASC`

Comment: @EugenKonkov fixed the question & answers