# sorting data by "value" from jsonb_each(), is reliable?

Tags: json, postgresql, sorting, jsonb, postgresql-9.5

Given `jsonb` type column and data structure like this:

`{
  "1": 10000.2,
  "2": 77.2,
  "3": -200.09,
  "4": 12.55
}`

Need retrieve result from  this json and sort by `VALUE`

```
SELECT * FROM jsonb_each(
 (SELECT jsonb_column FROM table WHERE id = 777)
) 
ORDER BY  VALUE  DESC 
LIMIT 100
```

Yes, this gives correct result, but question is, how reliable is ordering by `jsonb` type? (because `VALUE` is `jsonb` type). Will this always work correctly?

I don't want (if not necessary) explicit convert: `ORDER BY CAST(VALUE::TEXT AS NUMERIC)` because in json, there is ~ 500 000 elements and when converting, it takes 2X time, than  sorting just by `VALUE`

Comment: There is something similar - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25967778/order-by-json-data-type-postgres
Generally only proper casting gives you expected results.

Comment: @JosMac Just because of casting takes more time, interested if order by jsonb type also can be used. If not 100% reliable, then I will be use proper  casting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't mix data types for values that your order by, you **don't need cast**, if you do, it will be ordered as [documented](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-json.html#JSON-INDEXING).

> Object > Array > Boolean > Number > String > Null
>
> Object with n pairs > object with n - 1 pairs
>
> Array with n elements > array with n - 1 elements

so if you try your statement against such json:

```
{
  "date": "2016-10-10",
  "2": "-200.08",
  "3": -200.09,
  "some": "text", 
  "5":-200.08,
  "mt":"-200.09",
  "ar":[0,2]
}
```

Your get the order from above:

```
t=# SELECT *,pg_typeof(value) FROM jsonb_each((select a from jt where i = 7 )) order by value desc;
 key  |    value     | pg_typeof
------+--------------+-----------
 ar   | [0, 2]       | jsonb
 5    | -200.08      | jsonb
 3    | -200.09      | jsonb
 some | "text"       | jsonb
 date | "2016-10-10" | jsonb
 mt   | "-200.09"    | jsonb
 2    | "-200.08"    | jsonb
(7 rows)
```